# Plotting multiple segments of a dataset on a single graph with each line overlaid

Tags: python, pandas, plot, graph, line

Below is the merged file of two price feeds on EURUSD data. We are looking to visualise the path that "mispricings" take when 'misplacing_1' and 'mispricing_2' are >0. The exploitable variable is when the misplacing is greater than 6.

```
merged = data.merge(df, how='outer', on='Date')

merged['buy_B_sell_A'] = ((merged['sell_A'] - merged['buy_B'])*100000)
merged['mispricing_1'] = np.where(merged['buy_B_sell_A']>0, 1, 0)
merged['exploitable_1'] = np.where(merged['buy_B_sell_A']>6, 'Yes', 'no')
merged['buy_A_sell_B'] = ((merged['sell_B'] - merged['buy_A'])*100000)
merged['mispricing_2'] = np.where(merged['buy_A_sell_B']>0, 1, 0)
merged['exploitable_2'] = np.where(merged['buy_A_sell_B']>6, 'Yes', 'no')

merged = merged.fillna(method='ffill').dropna()
merged['Time'] =  merged.Date.dt.time
merged.head()
```

To then plot the mispricings on a single graph I used the below code

```
plt.figure(figsize=[15,5])
plt.plot(merged[['buy_B_sell_A','Date']].set_index('Date'))[100000:]#.rolling(window=10).mean().dropna())
plt.show()
```

Which gave a graph which looks like this

[image]

From here, we want to take all the independent events, when the mispricing (shown on y axis) is >0, and plot a graph with each of these events overlayed one another with time in seconds (or milliseconds) on the x axis and mispricing on the y axis.

We would then want to take an average of all the lines and create in essence a line of best fit.

The below is an example of having all the lines overlayed however is not with relevant data

[image]

we would then want to take the average of all the plotted lines to give one single line

What would be the best way to do this and any help would be greatly appreciated.TIA

- We are looking to plot the `buy_B_sell_A` values on a chart, when the `mispricing_1 column = 1`. In the data, there will be several consecutive rows where `mispricing_1= 1`. We want to group these consecutive 1 values and plot each group as an independent line on a graph, where all the lines are overlaid. Put simple, the graph with the blue lines shown above, we want to take every segment where it is above 0, and the plot all those individual segments ontop of each other to give a graph which looks like the one above with red lines.

The data set below is limited and may not have the condition 'misplacing_1=1'.

## Data

```py
Date,sell_A,buy_A,sell_B,buy_B,buy_B_sell_A,mispricing_1,exploitable_1,buy_A_sell_B,mispricing_2,exploitable_2,Time
2020-01-01 22:51:41.368,1.12144,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-26.999999999999247,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:51:41.368000
2020-01-01 22:51:41.978,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:51:41.978000
2020-01-01 22:51:43.189,1.12147,1.12171,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:51:43.189000
2020-01-01 22:51:43.731,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:51:43.731000
2020-01-01 22:51:57.360,1.12137,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:51:57.360000
2020-01-01 22:52:02.022,1.1213600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:02.022000
2020-01-01 22:52:02.024,1.12151,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:02.024000
2020-01-01 22:52:02.189,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:02.189000
2020-01-01 22:52:18.720,1.12142,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:18.720000
2020-01-01 22:52:20.066,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:20.066000
2020-01-01 22:52:42.802,1.12148,1.1217700000000002,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:42.802000
2020-01-01 22:52:42.972,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:42.972000
2020-01-01 22:52:45.320,1.1214899999999999,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:45.320000
2020-01-01 22:52:45.489,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:52:45.489000
2020-01-01 22:53:01.489,1.1214600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:01.489000
2020-01-01 22:53:20.940,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:20.940000
2020-01-01 22:53:22.823,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:22.823000
2020-01-01 22:53:22.826,1.1214600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:22.826000
2020-01-01 22:53:26.589,1.12148,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:26.589000
2020-01-01 22:53:27.929,1.1214600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:27.929000
2020-01-01 22:53:28.895,1.1214899999999999,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:28.895000
2020-01-01 22:53:38.038,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:38.038000
2020-01-01 22:53:39.027,1.12147,1.12171,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:39.027000
2020-01-01 22:53:39.244,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:39.244000
2020-01-01 22:53:51.144,1.1213600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:51.144000
2020-01-01 22:53:58.096,1.1213799999999998,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:53:58.096000
2020-01-01 22:54:03.460,1.1214899999999999,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:03.460000
2020-01-01 22:54:05.330,1.1214899999999999,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:05.330000
2020-01-01 22:54:21.404,1.1213799999999998,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:21.404000
2020-01-01 22:54:22.852,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:22.852000
2020-01-01 22:54:23.080,1.12145,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:23.080000
2020-01-01 22:54:40.278,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:40.278000
2020-01-01 22:54:41.143,1.12143,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:41.143000
2020-01-01 22:54:42.898,1.12145,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:42.898000
2020-01-01 22:54:47.548,1.12147,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:54:47.548000
2020-01-01 22:55:05.642,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:55:05.642000
2020-01-01 22:55:30.874,1.12133,1.12176,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:55:30.874000
2020-01-01 22:55:40.157,1.12132,1.12178,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:55:40.157000
2020-01-01 22:55:41.599,1.12133,1.12178,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:55:41.599000
2020-01-01 22:55:42.564,1.1214600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:55:42.564000
2020-01-01 22:56:12.622,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:56:12.622000
2020-01-01 22:56:12.945,1.12144,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:56:12.945000
2020-01-01 22:56:28.780,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:56:28.780000
2020-01-01 22:57:07.971,1.12145,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:07.971000
2020-01-01 22:57:27.648,1.12135,1.12174,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:27.648000
2020-01-01 22:57:29.527,1.12133,1.12174,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:29.527000
2020-01-01 22:57:30.644,1.12134,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:30.644000
2020-01-01 22:57:30.646,1.12143,1.1216700000000002,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:30.646000
2020-01-01 22:57:47.624,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:57:47.624000
2020-01-01 22:58:25.640,1.12144,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:58:25.640000
2020-01-01 22:58:29.615,1.12143,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:58:29.615000
2020-01-01 22:58:51.560,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:58:51.560000
2020-01-01 22:59:24.612,1.12142,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:24.612000
2020-01-01 22:59:40.937,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:40.937000
2020-01-01 22:59:50.980,1.12135,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:50.980000
2020-01-01 22:59:52.092,1.12131,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:52.092000
2020-01-01 22:59:52.525,1.12135,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:52.525000
2020-01-01 22:59:57.627,1.12135,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:57.627000
2020-01-01 22:59:58.951,1.12135,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,22:59:58.951000
2020-01-01 23:00:00.366,1.12141,1.12164,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:00.366000
2020-01-01 23:00:03.068,1.12142,1.1216700000000002,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:03.068000
2020-01-01 23:00:04.847,1.1214600000000001,1.12162,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:04.847000
2020-01-01 23:00:06.084,1.1214600000000001,1.12164,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:06.084000
2020-01-01 23:00:19.153,1.1213899999999999,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:19.153000
2020-01-01 23:00:20.209,1.12147,1.12165,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:20.209000
2020-01-01 23:00:24.538,1.1215,1.12166,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:24.538000
2020-01-01 23:00:25.054,1.12152,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:25.054000
2020-01-01 23:00:25.236,1.1214899999999999,1.12168,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:25.236000
2020-01-01 23:00:25.738,1.1214899999999999,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:25.738000
2020-01-01 23:00:26.257,1.1214899999999999,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:26.257000
2020-01-01 23:00:26.259,1.1214899999999999,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:26.259000
2020-01-01 23:00:27.074,1.12154,1.1216899999999999,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:27.074000
2020-01-01 23:00:28.086,1.12154,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:28.086000
2020-01-01 23:00:29.206,1.1215600000000001,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:29.206000
2020-01-01 23:00:29.376,1.1215899999999999,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:29.376000
2020-01-01 23:00:29.429,1.1215899999999999,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:29.429000
2020-01-01 23:00:29.723,1.1215899999999999,1.12174,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:29.723000
2020-01-01 23:00:32.376,1.1215899999999999,1.12175,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:32.376000
2020-01-01 23:00:32.823,1.1216,1.12175,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:32.823000
2020-01-01 23:00:35.094,1.1216,1.12174,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:35.094000
2020-01-01 23:00:35.313,1.12161,1.12175,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:35.313000
2020-01-01 23:00:35.316,1.12162,1.12175,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:35.316000
2020-01-01 23:00:35.317,1.12162,1.12176,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:35.317000
2020-01-01 23:00:36.054,1.12161,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:36.054000
2020-01-01 23:00:37.001,1.12162,1.12174,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:37.001000
2020-01-01 23:00:37.055,1.12161,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:37.055000
2020-01-01 23:00:40.232,1.12161,1.1217,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:40.232000
2020-01-01 23:00:45.904,1.12161,1.12171,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:45.904000
2020-01-01 23:00:48.687,1.12163,1.12171,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:48.687000
2020-01-01 23:00:48.864,1.12164,1.12171,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:48.864000
2020-01-01 23:00:49.186,1.12164,1.12173,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:49.186000
2020-01-01 23:00:50.347,1.12164,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:50.347000
2020-01-01 23:00:58.893,1.12166,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:58.893000
2020-01-01 23:00:59.591,1.12166,1.12173,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:00:59.591000
2020-01-01 23:01:01.089,1.12166,1.12172,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:01.089000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.094,1.12168,1.12178,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.094000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.097,1.12171,1.1218,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.097000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.100,1.12173,1.12188,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.100000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.104,1.1217700000000002,1.122,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.104000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.158,1.1217700000000002,1.12204,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.158000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.160,1.12179,1.12204,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.160000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.169,1.12181,1.1220700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.169000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.224,1.12181,1.12208,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.224000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.229,1.12181,1.12209,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.229000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.236,1.12181,1.12208,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.236000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.241,1.12181,1.1220700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.241000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.244,1.12181,1.12208,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.244000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.245,1.12181,1.12209,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.245000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.304,1.12181,1.1221,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.304000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.308,1.12179,1.1221299999999998,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.308000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.310,1.12179,1.12214,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.310000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.313,1.12179,1.1221299999999998,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.313000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.368,1.12179,1.12211,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.368000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.374,1.12179,1.1221299999999998,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.374000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.439,1.12179,1.12218,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.439000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.508,1.12179,1.1222,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.508000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.513,1.12179,1.1221700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.513000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.520,1.12182,1.1222,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.520000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.577,1.12182,1.12227,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.577000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.581,1.12182,1.12225,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.581000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.584,1.12182,1.12222,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.584000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.700,1.12182,1.12226,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.700000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.704,1.12182,1.12224,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.704000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.712,1.12182,1.1222299999999998,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.712000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.767,1.12182,1.1222,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.767000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.769,1.12182,1.12215,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.769000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.772,1.12182,1.1221700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.772000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.774,1.12186,1.1221700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.774000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.831,1.12186,1.12216,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.831000
2020-01-01 23:01:04.838,1.12186,1.1221700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:04.838000
2020-01-01 23:01:05.630,1.12185,1.1221700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:05.630000
2020-01-01 23:01:05.683,1.12186,1.1221700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:05.683000
2020-01-01 23:01:05.685,1.12186,1.12216,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:05.685000
2020-01-01 23:01:05.794,1.12186,1.12214,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:05.794000
2020-01-01 23:01:06.260,1.12184,1.12214,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:06.260000
2020-01-01 23:01:08.151,1.12185,1.12211,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:08.151000
2020-01-01 23:01:08.319,1.12184,1.12208,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:08.319000
2020-01-01 23:01:09.813,1.12182,1.1221,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:09.813000
2020-01-01 23:01:10.800,1.12184,1.12206,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:10.800000
2020-01-01 23:01:11.246,1.1218700000000001,1.12211,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:11.246000
2020-01-01 23:01:12.179,1.1217700000000002,1.12206,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:12.179000
2020-01-01 23:01:12.292,1.12178,1.12206,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:12.292000
2020-01-01 23:01:12.346,1.12178,1.1221,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:12.346000
2020-01-01 23:01:13.206,1.12186,1.12211,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:13.206000
2020-01-01 23:01:13.319,1.1218700000000001,1.12209,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:13.319000
2020-01-01 23:01:13.377,1.12186,1.12211,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:13.377000
2020-01-01 23:01:14.184,1.12178,1.1221,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:14.184000
2020-01-01 23:01:15.235,1.12186,1.12211,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:15.235000
2020-01-01 23:01:15.844,1.12188,1.12214,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:15.844000
2020-01-01 23:01:16.188,1.12178,1.12206,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:16.188000
2020-01-01 23:01:16.465,1.12178,1.1221,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:16.465000
2020-01-01 23:01:17.192,1.12184,1.1221,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:17.192000
2020-01-01 23:01:17.466,1.12178,1.1221,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:17.466000
2020-01-01 23:01:18.678,1.1218299999999999,1.12208,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:18.678000
2020-01-01 23:01:20.600,1.12181,1.12208,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:20.600000
2020-01-01 23:01:20.986,1.12181,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:20.986000
2020-01-01 23:01:22.447,1.1218299999999999,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:22.447000
2020-01-01 23:01:36.307,1.12181,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:36.307000
2020-01-01 23:01:37.792,1.12175,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:37.792000
2020-01-01 23:01:37.910,1.12172,1.1220700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:37.910000
2020-01-01 23:01:37.966,1.12171,1.1220700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:37.966000
2020-01-01 23:01:42.276,1.12172,1.1220700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:42.276000
2020-01-01 23:01:42.701,1.12172,1.12208,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:42.701000
2020-01-01 23:01:42.703,1.12172,1.1220700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:42.703000
2020-01-01 23:01:45.950,1.12172,1.12204,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:45.950000
2020-01-01 23:01:50.353,1.12172,1.12201,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:50.353000
2020-01-01 23:01:50.673,1.12171,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:50.673000
2020-01-01 23:01:50.726,1.12172,1.12201,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:50.726000
2020-01-01 23:01:52.020,1.12172,1.12202,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:52.020000
2020-01-01 23:01:53.072,1.12172,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:53.072000
2020-01-01 23:01:53.074,1.12171,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:53.074000
2020-01-01 23:01:53.130,1.12172,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:53.130000
2020-01-01 23:01:55.391,1.12172,1.12209,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:01:55.391000
2020-01-01 23:02:00.838,1.12172,1.1221,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:00.838000
2020-01-01 23:02:00.896,1.1216899999999999,1.1220700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:00.896000
2020-01-01 23:02:00.963,1.1217,1.12208,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:00.963000
2020-01-01 23:02:01.139,1.1216899999999999,1.1220700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:01.139000
2020-01-01 23:02:01.978,1.1217,1.12208,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:01.978000
2020-01-01 23:02:02.039,1.1216700000000002,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:02.039000
2020-01-01 23:02:03.516,1.1216899999999999,1.1220700000000001,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:03.516000
2020-01-01 23:02:04.626,1.1216899999999999,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:04.626000
2020-01-01 23:02:07.166,1.12166,1.12204,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:07.166000
2020-01-01 23:02:07.219,1.1216700000000002,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:07.219000
2020-01-01 23:02:07.276,1.1217,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:07.276000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.588,1.12182,1.12205,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.588000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.591,1.12182,1.1221,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.591000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.597,1.1218,1.12198,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.597000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.655,1.1217700000000002,1.12198,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.655000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.723,1.12185,1.12198,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.723000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.780,1.1218299999999999,1.12198,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.780000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.845,1.12191,1.12201,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.845000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.901,1.12182,1.12201,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.901000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.905,1.1218,1.12201,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.905000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.906,1.12186,1.12201,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.906000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.917,1.1217700000000002,1.12201,1.1216,1.12171,-24.000000000001798,0,0,-9.999999999998899,0,0,23:02:08.917000
2020-01-01 23:02:08.977,1.1217700000000002,1.12208,1.1218299999999999,1.12202,-24.999999999986144,0,0,-25.00000000000835,0,0,23:02:08.977000
2020-01-01 23:02:09.148,1.12189,1.12208,1.1218299999999999,1.12202,-24.999999999986144,0,0,-25.00000000000835,0,0,23:02:09.148000
2020-01-01 23:02:09.151,1.12178,1.12208,1.12185,1.12198,-19.999999999997797,0,0,-22.999999999995246,0,0,23:02:09.151000
2020-01-01 23:02:09.266,1.12188,1.12208,1.12185,1.12198,-19.999999999997797,0,0,-22.999999999995246,0,0,23:02:09.266000
2020-01-01 23:02:09.320,1.12184,1.12208,1.12185,1.12198,-19.999999999997797,0,0,-22.999999999995246,0,0,23:02:09.320000
```